# How to copy a folder of files from IOS App bundle resources to Documents Directory

Tags: ios, file, copy, bundle, nsdocumentdirectory

I would like to pre-populate a folder structure of txt files in an IOS App Documents Folder at app startup, copying a pre-prepared folder of files which I have added to my app bundle as resources.

How do I browse a hierarchical folder structure within the IOS App bundle and request the contents of each sub folder and then the contents of each file.

Answer (score 0):

To list items in App Bundle, you can use this code:

```
do {
    let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: Bundle.main.bundleURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
    for url in fileURLs {
        print("fileURL = \(url)")
    }
} catch let error {
    // Error Handle
}
```

To copy the folder "MyTextFiles" in App Bundle to your App Document Folder:

```
    do {
        guard let myTextFilesInBundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyTextFiles", withExtension: nil) else { return }
        let docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let myTextFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: docPath).appendingPathComponent("MyTextFiles")
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: myTextFilesInBundleURL, to: myTextFileURL)
    } catch let error {
        // Error Handle
    }
```

To do this on app startup, you can put this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `applicationDidBecomeActive`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this on Monday

Comment: I was hoping for some code that would create an exact copy of a hierarchy of folders, i.e. folders with sub folders which then contain sub folders possibly down to 4 levels. But you have given me some ideas and I will post an example here when I am done.